# How to add page numbers to APA citations in ConTeXt?

Tags: bibtex, context, apa-style, context-mkiv

I have created a basic document with APA citations using the course code for creating bibliographies in MK IV in APA format, as found at the [ConTeXt garden](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Bibliography_mkiv):

```
\setupbibtex[database={sample},sort=author]
\setuppublications[alternative=apa]
\starttext
    \placepublications[criterium=text]
\stoptext
```

To place citations on the page, I am using `\cite[articleID]`. As APA format is selected, this appears as `(Author, Year)` in the text, as expected. In some situations, as is explained in the [APA Formatting and Style Guide](http://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/560/02/), I need to include page number information. The resulting format should look like this example, also from the guide:

```
She stated, "Students often had difficulty using APA style" (Jones, 1998, p. 199), but she did not offer an explanation as to why.
```

How can I add this page number information to my APA citations in ConTeXt?

Comment: (Untested): `\cite[extras={, p.~199}][....]`

Comment: Yes, this answer works.

Comment: For those using BibLaTeX, [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/292708/30762) shows how to do the same thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `\cite[extras={, p.~199}][cite-key]`

Comment: `extras` is not documented anywhere in ConTeXt garden (https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/cite) does anyone know why this is?