# Referencing page number with only one reference

Tags: back-referencing

So I'm making this summary of a course where I've only been getting information from one book. Sometimes I want to show what page from the book a statement is taken from but I can't figure out a clean way of doing it.

Basically I would like to have something (in function) similar to:

"Statement[Book p123]"

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: if you use only one book you can start by a note that say `[number]` refers to page `number` from the book.

Answer (score 126, accepted):

This is quite easy with BibLaTeX, though for a single reference, it may seem a little like overkill (then again, it'll get you familiar).

Here's a minimal example:

**TeX File:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\begin{document}
Reference to the book: \cite{kopka2003guide}, and something found on some page:
\cite[p.~150]{kopka2003guide}.

% The content of the [] brackets is arbitrary.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

**Bib File:**

```
@book{kopka2003guide,
  title        = {Guide to LaTeX (Adobe Reader)},
  author       = {Kopka, H. and Daly, P.W.},
  isbn         = 9780321617743,
  year         = 2003,
  publisher    = {Pearson Education}
}
```

**Output**

[image: output]

Comment: how to cite mulit pages with the same method? lets say from page 150 to 153.

Comment: The text is arbitrary in the brackets, so you can just write `\cite[pp.~150--153]{kopka2003guide}`.

Comment: Could you explain why you use a tilde (~) instead of a normal whitespace between p. and the page number? What are the advantages over using a whitespace?

Comment: The tilde `~` is a non-breaking space.  Typically, LaTeX will prefer to break a line after a full stop (since this usually indicates the end of sentence), but in this case we want to avoid that hence the use of `~`.

Comment: `biblatex` users don't need the `p.~`, a language-dependent page prefix will be added automatically (if the style wants a page prefix): `\cite[150]{kopka2003guide}`

Comment: @moewe Do you know how to apply the same with '\supercite' rather than '\cite'?

Comment: @hesham What exactly do you mean? `biblatex` suppresses pre- and postnotes in `\supercite`.

Comment: @moewe Thanks I just figured it out.  That exactly what I meant "biblatex suppresses pre- and postnotes in `\supercite`," I wanted to cite page numbers with `\supercite` so I had to remove that 'suppression'.Redifining `\supercite` as follows did the job:

    `\DeclareCiteCommand{\supercite}[\mkbibsuperscript]
    {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
 \let\multicitedelim=\supercitedelim
    {\,}\bibopenbracket \usebibmacro{prenote}}%
    {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
 \usebibmacro{cite:comp}}
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:dump}\usebibmacro{postnote}\bibclosebracket}
    %`

Comment: The optional argument should be used carefully; I haven't seen the [1, p 150] notation used in literature yet; When using [1, eq. (20)], I got the comment "clarify if you mean eq. (20) in [1], or ref. [1] and eq. (20) in THIS document" as feedback, i.e. unless the notation is common in a field, it may be considered bad style.

Comment: cite[pg.~42]{Author-etc} doesn't work with \usepackage[strings]{underscore}. I haven't looked at that package to try to understand why that happens.