# Referencing specific page number when citing

Tags: natbib

I am aware that this exists: [Referencing page number with only one reference](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/292704/referencing-page-number-with-only-one-reference) however, my question expands upon it.

Tex file:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{agsm}

\begin{document}
Reference to the book  without parenthesis: \cite{kopka2003guide}
Reference to specific page without parenthesis: \cite[p. 150]{kopka2003guide}

Reference to the book with parenthesis: \citep{kopka2003guide}
Reference to specific page wit parenthesis: \citep[p. 150]{kopka2003guide}

\bibliography{references.bib}
\end{document}
```

Now I would expect to end up with something like this:

```
Reference to the book  without parenthesis: Kopka & Daly (2003)
Reference to specific page without parenthesis: Kopka & Daly (2003, p 150)

Reference to the book with parenthesis: (Kopka & Daly 2003)
Reference to specific page wit parenthesis: (Kopka & Daly 2003, p 150)
```

Instead I end up with this:

```
Reference to the book  without parenthesis: Kopka & Daly (2003)
Reference to specific page without parenthesis: (Kopka & Daly 2003, p 150)

Reference to the book with parenthesis: (Kopka & Daly 2003)
Reference to specific page wit parenthesis (Kopka & Daly 2003, p 150)
```

So is there any way to end up with an actual reference to a specific page without parenthesis (case 2)?

Bib file:

```
@book{kopka2003guide,
  title        = {Guide to LaTeX (Adobe Reader)},
  author       = {Kopka, H. and Daly, P.W.},
  isbn         = 9780321617743,
  year         = 2003,
  publisher    = {Pearson Education}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: This behaviour of `\cite` in author-year citations is the reason that officially the `natbib` documentation recommends not using `\cite` and instead recommends using `\citet` and `\citep`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked,

> So is there any way to end up with an actual reference to a specific page without parenthesis [around the author part of the citation call-out] (case 2)?

Yes: Just use `\citet` instead of `\cite`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{references.bib}
@book{kopka2003guide,
  title        = {Guide to LaTeX (Adobe Reader)},
  author       = {Kopka, H. and Daly, P.W.},
  isbn         = 9780321617743,
  year         = 2003,
  publisher    = {Pearson Education}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{har2nat} % to maximize compatibility with hyperref package
\bibliographystyle{agsm}

\begin{document}

Reference to the book  without parenthesis: \citet{kopka2003guide}

Reference to specific page without parenthesis: \citet[p.\ 150]{kopka2003guide}

\medskip
Reference to the book with parenthesis: \citep{kopka2003guide}

Reference to specific page with parenthesis: \cite[p.\ 150]{kopka2003guide}

\bibliography{references.bib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: excellent! thank you!